# Como interpretar respuesta de insert sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

estoy implementando sqlite en app, pero el insert me devuelve -1, como interpreto los mensajes.

Asi esta la funcion

```
 public long IngCliente(SQLiteDatabase db, cliente cliente) {
    return db.insert(
            clienterEntry.TABLE_CLIENTE,
            null,
            cliente.toContentValues());
}
```

De esta manera hago el llamado

```
resultado=mClienteDbHelper.nuevoCliente(new cliente("8787","nombre","Juan Montalvo","Cuenca","uno",""));
```

Otra pregunta, como puedo ver si la base fue creada?

ACTUALIZACIÓN
Esta es la clase de creacion de la base, no se donde esta el PATH

```
public class dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sis_cspm.db";

public dbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   // private static final String table_create_clientes =;
    db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + clienterEntry.TABLE_CLIENTE + " ( " +
            clienterEntry.C_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            clienterEntry.C_codigo + " TEXT, " +
            clienterEntry.C_nombre + " TEXT, " +
            clienterEntry. C_direccion + " TEXT, " +
            clienterEntry.C_ciudad + " TEXT, " +
            clienterEntry.C_tipo + " TEXT, " +
            clienterEntry.C_canal + " TEXT )");

    // Insertar datos ficticios para prueba inicial
    mockData(db);

}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // No hay operaciones
}
private void mockData(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

            IngCliente(sqLiteDatabase,new cliente("000","juan","Centro","Cuenca","Mayorista","UNO"));

}
public long IngCliente(SQLiteDatabase db, cliente cliente) {
    return db.insert(
            clienterEntry.TABLE_CLIENTE,
            null,
            cliente.toContentValues());
}
public long nuevoCliente(cliente cliente) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(
            clienterEntry.TABLE_CLIENTE,
            null,
            cliente.toContentValues());
   /* try {
        // Simulate network access.

    } catch (SQLiteAbortException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
    }
    return sqLiteDatabase;*/
}
public Cursor getAllClientes() {
    return getReadableDatabase()
            .query(
                    clienterEntry.TABLE_CLIENTE,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);
}
```

}

En la clase cliente tengo declarado el contentValue así.

```
public ContentValues toContentValues(){
    ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
    values.put(clienterEntry.C_id,cMAId);
    values.put(clienterEntry.C_codigo,cMACODIGO);
    values.put(clienterEntry.C_nombre,cMANOMBRE);
    values.put(clienterEntry.C_direccion,cMADIRECCION);
    values.put(clienterEntry.C_ciudad,cMACIUDAD);
    values.put(clienterEntry.C_tipo,cMATIPO);
    values.put(clienterEntry.C_canal,cMACANAL);
    values.put(clienterEntry.C_latitud,cMALATITUD);
    values.put(clienterEntry.C_longitud,cMALONGITUD);
    return  values;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Al insertar si obtienes -1 significa que no inserto el registro, cualquier otro valor es el id del registro insertado correctamente.

```
int resultado = db.insert(clienterEntry.TABLE_CLIENTE, null,cliente.toContentValues());
if(resultado== -1){
// Ocurrio un error al realizar la insercion.
}else{
// Se inserto el dato satisfactoriamente.
}
```

---

> **[Android SQLite insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))** : retorna el Id de fila de la fila recién insertada o -1 si se produjo un error

---

### ¿Como saber si la base de datos fue creada?.

Para esto necesitas saber el path en donde realizaste la creación de la base de datos, y usar este método, el cual intenta la conexión para determinar si existe en realidad.:

```
private boolean checkDataBase(String Database_path) {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Database_path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        checkDB.close();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // No existe la base de datos.
    }
    return checkDB != null;
}
```

---

#### ¿Porque tengo error al insertar?

Si revisas los datos que tratas de insertar al realizar el llamado, tanto aquí:

```
IngCliente(sqLiteDatabase,new cliente("000","juan","Centro","Cuenca","Mayorista","UNO"));
```

como aquí:

```
resultado=mClienteDbHelper.nuevoCliente(new cliente("8787","nombre","Juan Montalvo","Cuenca","uno",""));
```

coinciden de acuerdo a la estructura de la tabla,

```
  db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + clienterEntry.TABLE_CLIENTE + " ( " +
            clienterEntry.C_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            clienterEntry.C_codigo + " TEXT, " +
            clienterEntry.C_nombre + " TEXT, " +
            clienterEntry. C_direccion + " TEXT, " +
            clienterEntry.C_ciudad + " TEXT, " +
            clienterEntry.C_tipo + " TEXT, " +
            clienterEntry.C_canal + " TEXT )");
```

Pero los datos que tratas de insertar que son almacenados en el ContentValues no coinciden, tienes además, latitud y longitud.

```
ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
values.put(clienterEntry.C_id,cMAId);
values.put(clienterEntry.C_codigo,cMACODIGO);
values.put(clienterEntry.C_nombre,cMANOMBRE);
values.put(clienterEntry.C_direccion,cMADIRECCION);
values.put(clienterEntry.C_ciudad,cMACIUDAD);
values.put(clienterEntry.C_tipo,cMATIPO);
values.put(clienterEntry.C_canal,cMACANAL);
values.put(clienterEntry.C_latitud,cMALATITUD);
values.put(clienterEntry.C_longitud,cMALONGITUD);
return  values;
```

es muy común que realizando pruebas creamos una estructura diferente la cual no cambia, ya que la tabla existe y no intenta crearla nuevamente, te sugiero elimines la aplicación y la vuelvas a instalar.

Comment: Hice el check con la función que me indicabas, se ha creado la db, el error parece en el insert, que hago mal? tengo un huawei mate 9 para pruebas.

Comment: Bueno ese es otro tipo de problema diferente. Revisa lo que agrego como posibles causas, de hecho el content values tiene dos valores más, y trata de borrar tu aplicación si es que realizaste un cambio en la estructura. @AlldesignWeb